# Cobol - End terminator for write?

Tags: cobol

In Cobol, Is it required that we put at end-write after a write statement. For example consider the following:

```
write something from something after advancing 1 lines.
end-write.
```

Do we need to do it like the above? Or is just this fine:

```
write something from something after advancing 1 lines.
```

I don't get any compiler warnings when I compile without the `end-write` unlike when I don't use end-read or end-if I get compiler warnings.

Could someone help me understand this?

Comment: The only time an END-WRITE is required is when the WRITE statement is inside of another conditional statement, like an IF statement.  Neither the period nor the END-WRITE are required otherwise.

Comment: Your example is actually a compile error. There cannot be a full-stop/period "within" a structure that is terminated by a scope-delimiter, as the full-stop/period terminates *all* scopes, instantly. That is what is bad about using it, and why you should minimise its use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `END-WRITE` is only required when `INVALID KEY` or `NOT INVALID KEY` are used.

In *no other circumstance do you need* it. Although you can *always* use it if you want to.

I don't use `INVALID KEY/NOT INVALID KEY`, and never use `END-WRITE` (or `END-READ`, `END-OPEN`, `END-CLOSE`, `END-START`). Instead I use the `FILE STATUS` clause on the `SELECT` statement, and test the FILE STATUS field after each IO operation.

If you are getting used to writing modern COBOL (to the 1985 Standard) then you should avoid as many full-stops/periods in the `PROCEDURE DIVISION` as you can. After the PROCEDURE DIVISION header. After a paragraph/SECTION label. Before a paragraph/SECTION label. At the end of the program if not already used for another reason.

For the one before a paragraph/SECTION label, I include it full-stop/period on a line of its own, in column 12.

Comment: That's why the last line of any section/paragraph I write is a single ".", the only one of the section/paragraph.

Comment: Regarding the first line. `END-WRITE` is also used with `END-OF-PAGE` and `NOT END-OF-PAGE`.